# Prove that a signature scheme is RUF-NMA and not EUF-CMA

Tags: signature, diffie-hellman, attack, pairings

I am working on the following exercise:

> Now, assume the following signature scheme:
>
> $\operatorname{KeyGen} (1^k$) : On input of a security parameter $k$, choose a symmetric bilinear group with $e : G \times G \rightarrow G_T$ where the common group order of $G$ and $G_T$ is a prime of bitlength $k$. Further, let $g$ generate $G$. Choose $\mathit{sk}$ randomly from $Z_p$ and $\mathit{pk} \leftarrow  g^{\mathit{sk}}$ and return $(\mathit{sk}; \mathit{pk})$.
>
> $\operatorname{Sign} (\mathit{sk};m)$ : On input of a secret key $\mathit{sk}$ and a message $m$, output a signature $\sigma \leftarrow  m^{sk}$.
>
> $\operatorname{Verify} (\mathit{pk}; m; \sigma)$ : On input of a public key $\mathit{pk}$, a message $m$ and a signature $\sigma$, return $1$ if the following holds and $0$ otherwise:
> $$e(m; \mathit{pk}) = e(\sigma; g)$$

I showed that the scheme works correctly. Now I need to show that the scheme is

1. random message unforgeable under no message attacks (RUF-NMA)
2. is not existentially unforgeable under chosen message attacks (EUF-CNMA)

Concerning point 1) I think that being able to guess the signature for a given message $m$ and a given public key $\mathit{pk}$ would violate the computational Diffie Hellmann assumption in symmetric bilinear groups (CDHSBG). But how could I write that down more formally?

Concerning 2) I suppose I have to find a suiting example for such an attack, but I am struggeling to find one.

Could you help me?

Comment: 1) You need to come up with a reduction that transforms any attacker agains RUF-NMA into an algorithm that can solve CDH. Hint: Given $g^x$ and $g^y$, how do you need to choose $pk$ and $m$, such that the signature equals $g^{xy}$. 2) Given two signatures $\sigma_1=m_1^{sk}$ and $\sigma_2=m_2^{sk}$ do you see any way to combine them into a signature of a new message?

Comment: Concerning 2) : I suppose you mean that $\sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2$ is the signature of $m_1 \cdot m_2$ right? Concerning 1) I do not understand why you say "choose m" since we are considering a no message attack here

Comment: 2) Indeed. 1) *You* in this scenario are the reduction. You have *access* to a supposed attacker against RUF-NMA security. This attacker expects as input a public key and a message. You can choose those inputs, as long as you take care that they are correctly distributed.

Comment: I think I got it now: Since $ \sigma := m^{sk} =$ $g^{a \cdot sk}$ for some $a \in Z_p$  $= g^a \cdot g^{sk} = g^a \cdot pk$  by definition of $pk$  we found  a CDH solver right?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by that last part.

Comment: I meant since $pk←g^sk$ (from the exercise sheet above) we can say $pk = g^{sk}$. I should probably add that we should set $g^x := g^a$ and $g^y := pk$ in the noation of your comment above.